# Combine queries or making 1 query

Tags: ms-access

I am currently attempting to create a database for work, I have never used Access before. So far I have managed to create a data entry form that feeds a _be table.

What I am trying to do now is be able to query the total number of records in 3 formats (YTD,MTD,WTD) and then group by "airplane model"  which i have managed to accomplish separately. The problem is when I try to put that data on a report I have to create subreports to include all 3 queries.

Is there a way to put all of this in 1 query or merge the queries I have without compromising data? So far when I attempt to use Union or Join the data doesn't feed correctly. The fields I am querying off of are the same for each query, just the dates are criteria differently.

YTD SQL

```
SELECT [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model], Count(*) AS [This Year]
FROM [BlueStreak Tracking1]
WHERE ((([BlueStreak Tracking1].[Issue Date]) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),12,31)))
GROUP BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model]
ORDER BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model];
```

MTD SQL

```
SELECT [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model], Count(*) AS [This Month]
FROM [BlueStreak Tracking1]
WHERE (((Year([Issue Date]))=Year(Date())) AND ((Month([Issue Date]))=Month(Date())))
GROUP BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model]
ORDER BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model];
```

WTD SQL

```
SELECT [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model], Count(*) AS [This Week]
FROM [BlueStreak Tracking1]
WHERE ((([BlueStreak Tracking1].[Issue Date]) Between DateAdd("d",-((Weekday(Date())-1)),Date()) And Date()))
GROUP BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model]
ORDER BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model];
```

Comment: Have you tried joining the 3 queries to master table of airplane models? Edit question to provide sample raw data - as text, not image. Might remove the ORDER BY from each query to simplify. Do the ordering in final query or in report design.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the data doesn't feed correctly?"  Are you validating results?  Have you used UNION ALL or just UNION?

Comment: Yes I go and manually validate the data. The database is still being tested so there isnt a bunch records to sort through right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it in a Union All. See if this works:

```
SELECT [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model], 'This Year' as [TimeFrame], Count(*)
FROM [BlueStreak Tracking1]
WHERE ((([BlueStreak Tracking1].[Issue Date]) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1) 
And DateSerial(Year(Date()),12,31)))
GROUP BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model]

UNION ALL

SELECT [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model], 'This Month', Count(*) 
FROM [BlueStreak Tracking1]
WHERE (((Year([Issue Date]))=Year(Date())) AND ((Month([Issue Date]))=Month(Date())))
GROUP BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model]

UNION ALL

SELECT [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model], 'This Week',  Count(*) 
FROM [BlueStreak Tracking1]
WHERE ((([BlueStreak Tracking1].[Issue Date]) Between DateAdd("d",- 
((Weekday(Date())-1)),Date()) And Date()))
GROUP BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model]
ORDER BY [BlueStreak Tracking1].[Airplane Model];
```

Comment: I don't think UNION is desirable. Probably prefer to keep each count in its own column.

Comment: Yes, that could be. Possibly make a separate column for each, with a null/0 coming from each of the other queries.

Comment: But a JOIN as suggested in comment under question should accomplish that. Not an INNER JOIN, though.

Comment: I do want to keep each date criteria it's own column, I've been able to do it once, but each column while named properly had all the YTD data in them.

Comment: Doesn't a join overlay two matching columns. The whole union/join thing confuses me

Comment: A join pulls columns from tables based on a specific criteria you give it, like A1 = B1. So if A1 is not equal to B1, it will not pull the data from B1 if it is a left join, and it won't pull from either table if it is an inner join.

A Union adds records together - think of it as a copy/paste from one or more spreadsheet to another. It copies records from the tables in the union into one table, either removing duplicates (union or union distinct) or keeping all (Union All).

Comment: @wavery your SQL worked, just not the way i had envisioned. It broke the YTD,MTD,WTD into rows for each model. Is it possible to have it broken into individual columns?